# How to create .msi installer with WIX in Azure Devops?

Tags: azure-devops, msbuild, wix, windows-installer, azure-yaml-pipelines

I am trying to create a .msi installer package with wix for my dektop app in azure devops using yaml scripting. Below is the msbuild task created for the same:

```
- task: MSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '**/*.wixproj'
#    platform: 'Any CPU'
    configuration: 'Release'
    msbuildArguments: '/p:Configuration=Release/p:ProductCode=${product_code} /p:UpgradeCode=${upgrade_code}/t:Clean;Rebuild'
    clean: true
```

Below is the error i'm getting during the pipeline build:

```
 Error MSB3441: Cannot get assembly name for "..\MyProject\bin\Release\MyProject.exe". Could not load file or assembly 'MyProject.exe' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

We had this problem too. Our solution was to remove the Installer project from the Solution file, continue building the other projects in the solution using the standard `MSBuild` task and then add `script` tasks to the pipeline to generate the MSI:

```
pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

steps:
    - script: .\Tools\Wix\candle.exe -nologo Foobar.wxs -out Foobar.wixobj -ext WixUIExtension
      displayName: 'Compile Wix file'
    
    - script: .\Tools\Wix\light.exe -nologo Foobar.wixobj -out Foobar.msi -ext WixUIExtension
      displayName: 'Create MSI file'
```

Note that our build is based on the `windows-latest` image which includes WiX Toolset; see the list of all included tools [here](https://github.com/actions/runner-images/blob/main/images/windows/Windows2022-Readme.md).

Answer (score 1):

I don't have custom arguments, so maybe that's the difference here, but I used the templated msbuild task that Azure Pipelines gives you. It produced the below yaml and it builds the msi just fine in the pipeline.

```
- task: MSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '**/*.wixproj'
    msbuildArchitecture: 'x64'
    platform: 'x64'
    configuration: 'Release'
  displayName: 'build installer'
```